# When should we define a new intent vs add a new intent in wit.ai story?

Tags: wit.ai

I am experimenting with creating chatbots using wi.ai and I had following questions regarding usage of "intent" in a wit.ai story.

When do I ..

1. create a new intent?
2. use a existing intent but give it new values ?
3. create a new story ?

I feel this distinction is not very evident from their [documentation](https://wit.ai/docs).

Answer (score 0):

You create a new intent when you have a new question to answer. i.e. do you want to play soccer?

The intent there is to find out if someone plays soccer so you would create an intent for say "soccer" if you already have other sports answered in a similar way. So all future variations of the question of playing soccer i.e. "bro do u even soccer"? would map to the soccer internet

A new story is for an entirely different subject or maybe a variant of the same question that is sufficiently different enough i.e. how long have you been playing soccer?

I was lost when I first got into Wit too and didn't know where to start.